# mongodb how to project first child

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I got a mongo db collection with structure

randomstring - means the string is actually random its diffrent in each document of the collection.

```
{
   "notrandom":{
     "randomstring":{
       "randomstring":{
          "randomstring":{
              "notrandom2":"data"
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

how can i project this data out?
something like

```
db.mydb.aggregate( "notrandom[0][0].notrandom2":1}} , ]  )
```

what i'm trying to achieve is a collection of all the `notrandom2` values.

Comment: What kind of `aggregate` query it is? Please give a proper query, that you have tried so far.

Comment: "randomstring" is a random string.......

Comment: `notrandom[0][0]` you can use this way if `randomstring` is an array.

Comment: its not an array. its an object.

Comment: Please see the answer. Is it helping you?

Comment: Hi, @Nahum. Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

if you you to move `notrandom2` to higer level in document structure, 
you could use `$project` stage like this:

```
{
   $project:{
      _id:1,
      notrandom2:"notrandom.randomstring.randomstring.randomstring.notrandom2",
      // list all others fields with field:1 if you want them to appear down in pieline 
}}
```

if this field is a part of an array then you need to `$unwind` first and then `$project`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query

```
db.mydb.find({<findquery (in you have any)>},{"notrandom.randomstring.randomstring.randomstring.notrandom2" : 1}).
toArray(function(err, result)
{
     console.log(result); //Array of objects with `notrandom2` values
})
```

Comment: please add quotes around notrandom... as this will be taken as a variable